# Close Event Triggers Before Data Events on File Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I've got a script that adds JSON data from a file to a DynamoDB table. The script uses the "fs" module to open a read stream to the json file and retrieve the data line by line. As the data is returned, it's inserted into a DynamoDB table. When the operation ends, an execution summary is given with number of records processed, successfully inserted, and unsuccessfully inserted. The problem is the summary executes before the file has completely processed. As result the numbers are wrong.

The script...

```
ddb_table_has_records(table_name, (err, dat) => {
  if (dat.Count === 0 || force) {
    const transformStream = JSONStream.parse("*");
    const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(import_file);

    let record_position = 0;
    let count_imported_successful = 0;
    let count_imported_fail = 0;

    inputStream.pipe(transformStream).on("data", (Item) => {
      const params = {
        TableName: table_name,
        Item
      }

      ddb_client.put(params, (err, data) => {
        ++record_position;

        if (err) {
          console.error("Unable to add mapping for record " + record_position + ", error = " + err);
          ++count_imported_fail;
        } else {
          console.log("PutItem succeeded " + record_position);
          ++count_imported_successful;
        }
      });
    }).on("close", () => {
      console.log("=".repeat(70));
      console.log(`'Completed: ${import_file}' has been loaded into '${table_name}'.`);

      console.log(` Record Count: ${record_position}`);
      console.log(` Imported Record Count: ${count_imported_successful}`);
      console.log(` Rejected Record Count: ${count_imported_fail}`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("=".repeat(70));
    console.log(`Completed: Skipping import of '${import_file}' into '${table_name}'.`);
  };
});
```

When this runs, it looks like the following

```
PS C:\> node --max-old-space-size=8192 .\try.js 'foo' 'us-west-2' 'development' '.\data.json' true
Target Profile:  development
Target Region:  us-west-2
Target Table:  foo
Source File:  .\data.json
Force Import:  true
Confirming Table's State...
======================================================================
'Completed: .\data.json' has been loaded into 'foo'.
 Record Count: 0
 Imported Record Count: 0
 Rejected Record Count: 0
PutItem succeeded 1
PutItem succeeded 2
PutItem succeeded 3
PutItem succeeded 4
...
```

The portion of the code that gets the record counts runs before the inserts completes so the records imported and rejected numbers are always wrong. It looks like the file stream closes while inserts are occurring. I've tried changing from the "close" to "end" event, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this script with the following call...

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 .\data.load.js 'foo' 'us-west-1' 'dev' '.\foo.default.json' true
```

Here is the content for the script I ultimately used...

```
'use strict'

if (process.argv.length < 6) {
    throw new Error ('Please pass the table-name, aws-Region, aws-Profile, and file-path to the script.');
}

let [, , TableName, Region, Profile, ImportFile, Force] = process.argv;

process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = true;
process.env.AWS_PROFILE = Profile;

Force = typeof(Force) !== 'undefined' ? Force : false;

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

AWS.config.update({ region: Region });

const ddbc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log('Target Profile: ', Profile);
console.log('Target Region: ', Region);
console.log('Target Table: ', TableName);
console.log('Source File: ', ImportFile);
console.log('Force Import: ', Force);

// Returns the number of records in a specified table
const ddb_table_has_items = (TableName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ddb_query_parameters = { TableName, Select: 'COUNT' }

        ddbc.scan(ddb_query_parameters, (error, data) => {
            (error) ? reject(error) : resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

const ddb_table_upsert_items = (TableName, Item) => {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
        const ddb_insert_payload = { TableName, Item };

        ddbc.put(ddb_insert_payload, (error, data) => {
            (error) ? reject(error) : resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

const ddb_bulk_load = (TableName, ImportFile) => {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
        let count_succeeded = 0;
        let count_failed = 0;
        let count_attempted = 0;
        let inserts = [];

        const json_stream = JSONStream.parse( "*" );
        const source_data_stream = fs.createReadStream(ImportFile);
        const ddb_source_item = source_data_stream.pipe(json_stream);

        ddb_source_item.on("data", (source_data_item) => {
            count_attempted++;

            let ddb_insert = ddb_table_upsert_items(TableName, source_data_item)
                .then( (data) => count_succeeded++ )
                .catch( (error) => count_failed++ );

            inserts.push(ddb_insert);
        });

        ddb_source_item.on("end", () => {
            Promise.all(inserts)
                .then(() => {
                    resolve({count_succeeded, count_failed, count_attempted});
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                });
        });

        ddb_source_item.on("error", (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        let proceed_with_import = false;

        if ( Force.toString().toLowerCase() === 'true' ) {
            proceed_with_import = true;
        } else {
            const table_scan = await ddb_table_has_items(TableName);
            proceed_with_import = ( table_scan.Count === 0 );
        }

        if (proceed_with_import) {
            let ddb_inserts = await ddb_bulk_load(TableName, ImportFile);

            console.log("=".repeat(75));
            console.log("Completed: '%s' has been loaded into '%s'.", ImportFile, TableName);
            console.log(" Insert Attempted: %s", ddb_inserts.count_attempted);
            console.log(" Insert Succeeded: %s", ddb_inserts.count_succeeded);
            console.log(" Insert Failed   : %s", ddb_inserts.count_failed);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Wrapping each insert in a promise, pushing the insert-promises into an array, and using promise all on that array did the trick. I execute the promise all once we're finished reading from the file; once the "end" event is emitted on the `ddb_source_item` stream.